# Use in operator in stored query in ms access with ado.net

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

Following is my stored query in ms access

```
UPDATE tblContacts SET isActive = 0, DtUpdated = vDtUpdated
WHERE ContactId in (vContactId);
```

ContactId is integer.

Following is my c# code which executes the above stored query

```
    public void Delete(string contactId)
        {
            using (var cm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cm.Connection = AccessConnection();
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cm.CommandText = "deltblContacts";
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("vDtUpdated", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("vContactId", contactId);
                cm.Connection.Open();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cm.Connection.Close();
      }
}
```

When i execute the above code, not a single record is affected.

I feel that passing data to the stored query in string form is the pain point.

Comment: First, why not make the query: "UPDATE tblContacts SET isActive = 0, DtUpdated = vDtUpdated
WHERE ContactId = vContactId;" if you're only ever deleting one contact ID at a time? Second, can we see the whole stored query including the parameters that are passed?

Comment: i am deleting multiple records. And the stored query is in full. Parameters are vDtUpdated as datetime and vContactId are list of contact ids like 153,521,14,15,18,13